# (Oracle Database 11g) unique constraint violated coming in INSERT/UPDATE

Tags: oracle11g

Why do i still get a error even I made my value unique?
What I did was first to create the table including the primary keys, and insert the values inside the tables and now I'm trying to add the foreign keys and that's where the problem starts to occur, when I try to alter the table DEPT_Table

```
create table DEPT_Table(
Dname varchar(15),
Dnumber varchar(6),
Mgr_num varchar(10),
EMP_START_DATE date);
```

and insert this

```
insert into DEPT_Table values ('HRAdmin','DTHRA1','MHRA111',TO_DATE('1/8/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

and try to connect it to my DEPT_Loc

```
create table Dept_Loc(
  Dnumber varchar(8),
  DLocation varchar(8));
```

```
insert into Dept_Loc values('DLHRA1','BLDG1F2');
```

It still gets a error, I already tried to make my values unique as possible and each of the respective Departments are named `"DTHRA1"` for the Dept_Tables and `"DLHRA1"` for the department location but it still gets the error `ORA-00001: unique constraint violated`

what can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Seems there's no `"DLHRA1"` in your primary table. I think you are referring to `"DTHRA1"`

```
insert into Dept_Loc values('DTHRA1','BLDG1F2');
```

Comment: so I must have ```"DLHRA1"``` in my primary? but I thought when doing foreign key and referring it the value of the FK is unique? what i did before was there is no DLH and DTH, only DHRA1 for both tables

Comment: from what i understand from your problem is that you are trying to insert DLHRA1 in your Dept_Loc, but wont allow you because this doesn't exist in your primary table Dept_Table, your Dept_Loc->Dnumber has foreign key in your Dept_TAble->DNumber

Comment: I think this will be harder without visualization, please check this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/pk07lr
I made you a visualization in excel to make it easier, and also for you to  full view of my work in progress the ID I used in excel was before I try to alter the table so they all look the same